# filter sensible data from graphql response on strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

There are some information in my models, that should only be visible for some users. How can I alter the GraphQL response, in order to make sure that no sensible data is leaking the server?

I had partly success by overriding the `find` method in the controller of the model. I can alter/remove fields like this:

```
  async find(ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.article.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.article.find(ctx.params);
    }

    return entities.map(entity => {
        // filter information here e.g.
        entity.name = ""; // name will be always empty in the GraphQL response
        return entity; 
    });
  }
```

But, for nested models I cannot filter it. Example:

`Article` has many `Documents`. Some Documents should not be visible, but the GraphQL response does not respect if I remove the data:

```
//...
    return entities.map(entity => {
        // filter information here e.g.
        entity.name = "";
        entity.documents = []; // does not have any effect. Documents are still in the GraphQL response
        return entity;
    });
```

Comment: Hello! What are the conditions to display documents?